# Can a scala class instance spawn a variable not defined in its constructor?

Tags: scala, oop

I wonder if I can "patch" a variable onto an instance of a scala class.

The particular application is to fit statistical models à la scikit-learn (python):

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
lr = LogisticRegression() 

hasattr(lr, "coef_") # False

lr.fit([[2,3],[3,3]], [0,1])
hasattr(lr, "coef_") # True
```

sklearn checks if `coef_` is present to define the "fitted" state of a model object ([check_is_fitted](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L1035) essentially looks for attributes ending in _).

What I have tried:

- Forbidding unfitted states - I have worked around the problem by not allowing users to instantiate unfitted models, i.e. the class constructor requires input data to be fitted

  - This is ok ATM so I am mostly being curious here
  - That said, having unfitted states could later be handy to enable model pipelines (e.g. [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_feature_selection_pipeline.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-feature-selection-pipeline-py))
- Using mutable variables initialised with random numbers (see dummy example below)

  - That's ok if I know the type and shape of the coefficients, though instantiating them with random values can be difficult in some cases (depends on the model)
  - I hit a roadblock when writing interfaces around external models; for example if my `fit` method calls [this logistic regression implementation](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/core/src/main/java/smile/classification/LogisticRegression.java), how am I supposed to access/initialise the underlying [coeffients](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/core/src/main/java/smile/classification/LogisticRegression.java#L150)?

```scala
class StatsModel{
     var coef: Vector[Int] = Vector(0,0)
     var isFitted: Boolean = false
     
     def fit = {
         coef = Vector(1,2)
         isFitted = true
    } 
}
```

```
@ val m = new StatsModel() 
m: StatsModel = ammonite.$sess.cmd44$StatsModel@62cf8fda

@ m.isFitted 
res46: Boolean = false

@ m.fit 


@ m.isFitted 
res48: Boolean = true
```

Comment: The real problem here is that you are trying to use a Scala library as if it were a Python library. Read [the documentation for the Scala version](https://haifengl.github.io/api/scala/smile/classification/index.html)  to work out how it should be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I followed the same convention by requiring input data to fit the object when it is instantiated, so I don't really have a problem. Sorry if my q sounds like "how can do monkey patching in Scala", I just wonder if/how I could implement fitted states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't do that in Scala (all sorts of black magic is possible in the JVM via reflection (I'm not saying there's a way it could be accomplished via reflection, mind), but that's not really Scala *per se*).

A purer Scala approach would be along the lines of modeling

- a regression with coefficients which has not been fit
- a regression with coefficients which has been fit

as different types

e.g.

```scala
sealed trait StatsModel {
  def coefficients: Seq[Int]

  def fit(a: Seq[Seq[Int]], b: Seq[Int]): StatsModel

  /* Might not actually need this, but if there's a chance of multiple kinds of fitted or unfitted models, this might come in handy.
   * We'll use the JVM's v-table to resolve this, though if there are a lot of instances, defining a pattern match here might be more performant.
   */
  def isFit: Boolean
}

object StatsModel {
  case object Unfitted extends StatsModel {
    def coefficients: Seq[Int] = Nil
    def isFit: Boolean = false

    def fit(a: Seq[Seq[Int]], b: Seq[Int]): Fitted = ???
  }

  case class Fitted(override val coefficients: Vector[Int]) extends StatsModel {
    def isFit: Boolean = false

    def fit(a: Seq[Seq[Int]], b: Seq[Int]): StatsModel = this  // no need to perform the fit again...
  }
}
```

Comment: Super helpful, thanks. Is that "purer" because it keeps everything immutable (hence objects instead of classes)? Would the intended usage be something like `val initializedModel = Unfitted; val readyForPredictions: Fitted = initializedModel.fit(List(List(1,2,3), List(3,2,1), List(0,1))`?

Comment: Yeah, pure in the sense of trying to not side-effect.  That rough usage is what I would think of there.  I chose `Seq` in order to allow either `List` or `Vector` (among other possibilities).